# Primefaces extension timepiker break when minutes reach 0

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces, primefaces-extensions

I am using the primefaces extension 3.0.0 timepicker component, when spinning the time break when minutes reaches 0 with below jquery exception. The showcase works but not sure why its breaking for me. I am not good with jquery so any help is appreciated.

```
<pe:timePicker value="#{bean.schedule.endTime}"  
                                               widgetVar="endTimeWidget" showNowButton="true" showPeriod="true"/>
```

exception

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined timepicker.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces-extensions&v=3.0.0:55PrimeFacesExt.widget.TimePicker.PrimeFaces.widget.BaseWidget.extend.isAm timepicker.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces-extensions&v=3.0.0:55PrimeFacesExt.widget.TimePicker.PrimeFaces.widget.BaseWidget.extend.spin timepicker.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces-extensions&v=3.0.0:52$.children.removeClass.off.on.mousedown timepicker.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces-extensions&v=3.0.0:50bI.event.dispatch jquery.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=5.1:25ce.handle
```

Answer (score 0):

i thing that it has to do with the library. try clearing the external library from your application server. (I mean the priemfaces extensions jar in fact every edition 3.0.0 or less) Then remove the library from your application too. if u just added the jar then remove it as a jar and not as a library. If u created a library for adding the primefaces extensions jar then remove that one too from your development environment. You dont mention the envrinment so i cant help more with that. After you clear all references to the jar of the primefaces extensions then re-add the jar back again. I think the problem indicates misplacement of the jar file of some kind of blocking with another version maybe...?
Even though it says a property is has wrong value it actually cant find something in the library. That has happened to me once and this have solved it. good luck

Comment: I am using  Maven and the GF4 web server. I had clear the maven repository. But still the problem remains.